# Can't get hover effect in IE8 on Windows XP

Tags: css, windows-xp, hover

I have a structure  like this

```
       ul
         li
            div(class cls)
                table
                    tr
                     td
                        div 
                            a
```

I have applied css for the anchor element like this

```
    ul li .cls a:hover
    {
      background: #264A6A;
    }
```

It works perfectly on all browsers including IE8 on Windows 7. But on Windows XP on IE8 it does on change the background on hover.

What change needs to be done here?

Comment: any demo ? i've never be faced with this case

Comment: u can have a look at this jsfiddle.net/htmltester5/UVtr9/2

Comment: i've have a look at ie8 on xp, and it seems that the hover effect is still available...maybe you can try it on another computer...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UVtr9/6/, i found two errors in the html, just have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try `display:block` on anchor tag that would be the solution for that .Hopefully you will get your solution.

Comment: I'd better suggest `inline-block` with a CSS hack targeted only for IE8: http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/

Comment: ya you can use that as well :-)

Comment: Tried assigning display:block for anchor. But didn't help.

Comment: Ok. On my page i have this structure nested inside some elements. Also another difference is that this complete structure shows up after i hover on another element on page. But other than that there is no change in css.

Comment: What might possible be going wrong? Also can you suggest me a online tool for testing my site across all browsers n operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply being more specific:

```
ul li div.cls table tr td div a:hover
{
  background: #264A6A;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but to no effect. Still doesn't show the hovering effect.

Comment: @manu5987 - There must be something other code on your page affecting this then as here is a demo showing it working which I've tested on IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/akasR/2/